# ACF best practice - multiple get_field vs one get_fields

Tags: php, wordpress, optimization, advanced-custom-fields

In a case where a post have a few dozen custom fields and I just need two or three, **in term of performance and optimisation**, is it better to do one request getting every fields with

> [get_fields()](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

or multiple requests getting a single field with

> [get_field($field_name)](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/)

and if it depends (on the post's total number of fields, the number of fields needed, etc), at which point does one solution become better than the other ?

Comment: It looks like the get_fields() function is most useful for if you don't already know all the field names (using some sort of dynamic field generation) or if all of the fields are the same field type. For example, if you had a repeater, 3 select fields, a radio button group, 3 page link fields, and a relationship field, I think that the get_fields() would get very cumbersome very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you use **get_field()**, you create a new query to the database. So, generally speaking, it would be a good idea to use **get_fields()** first, to cache all the results, then **get_field()** where needed.

For example:

```
get_fields();

$field1 = get_field('field1');
$field2 = get_field('field2');
```

Still, if you have lots of fields, with large data in them, and you only need two of them, it might be better to just use **get_field()** twice, instead of increasing the load of the DB server and filling the cache with useless data.